# CSS to set the background color of dropdownlist on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my MVC Razor layout view I am trying to set the background color of my dropdown list on mouse hover:

```
The list looks like this:
            <li class="dropdown">
                                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Partner <b class="caret"></b></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="background-color:#080808">
                                        <li class="marv-main-li">@Html.ActionLink("Test1", "Action1", "Partner")</li>
                                        <li class="marv-main-li">@Html.ActionLink("Test2","Action2","Partner")</li>

                                        <li class="marv-main-li">@Html.ActionLink("Test3","Action3","Partner")</li>
                                        <li class="marv-main-li">@Html.ActionLink("Test4","Action4","Partner")</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>}
```

I tried this css which didnt work:

```
 .dropdown .dropdown-menu .li a:hover {
                background-color: #06fa12;

            }
```

How can I change the background color of the text in the dropdown list on mouse hover event?

I am using Twitter bootsrtap 3

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a type-error

Answer (score 2):

Since `<li>` is not a class, you should remove the dot before the li in your stylesheet.

Something like this

```
.dropdown .dropdown-menu li a:hover {
            background-color: #06fa12;
        }
```

Comment: This did not work. This is weird, I can see the css when I inspect elements but the background color just does not change

Comment: Note that you can also set the :hover directly on your <li> like this:
 .dropdown .dropdown-menu li:hover

Comment: This did not work. Can you please demonstrate this in fiddler? Thank you

Comment: Maybe you could post a jsfiddle with the html and css used to display your dropdown. It would be easier to understand your problem. It would also be easier to show you how to solve it directly in this jsfiddle that will fit your needs.

Answer (score -1):

It is impossible to change a parent element by hovering on a child element.  Here is a javascript solution with jQuery.

http://jsbin.com/uWupAtE/1/

```
$(function() {
  var ul = $('.Parent'),
      li = $('.Child');

  li.mouseover(function() {
    ul.addClass('hovered');                      
  });
  li.mouseout(function() {
    ul.removeClass('hovered');
  });
});
```

Comment: **I'm not sure what you're expecting this to do**.

Comment: I am expecting that when I click on the drop-down on my menu then  mouse over each element in the list the background  color changes